# send image in email body in android

Tags: android

I want to send email with image embedded in its body. Image tag is not rendering properly in my email after or before sending image.

Android Code:

```
Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);           
emailIntent1.setType("text/html");
emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("<html><head></head><body style=\"text-align:justify;\">").append("<div>").append("<img src =\"http://www.wechare.com/wp-content/uploads/banner.png\"/>")
            .append("</div>").append(" </body></html>");
String body = builder.toString();
emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body);
startActivity(emailIntent1);
```

HTML code :

```
<html>
        <head></head>
        <body style="text-align:justify;">
        <div>
        <img src="http://i2.wp.com/blog.smartthings.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/8795800-android-background.jpg?fit=683%2C405" />
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: the html content seems correct. How are you viewing the generated email?

Comment: u just need to send the image link so that it display in the email?

Comment: @Shine on my email it didn't show the image its ignore the img tag in email .. i want to show this image in my email

Comment: @Ramz yes i want to send the image link

Answer (score 0):

the html content seems correct, could it be a visualization issue? Are you allowed to see external content in the email client you're using to test?

Moreover, as `Html.fromHtml()` [returns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) a Spannable, ready to be used as TextView content, I would try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but work only with real device.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
emailIntent.setType("image/png");

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.file1);

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri));

startActivity(emailIntent);
```